# .net grid to display rows, and also have option to group by

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting

Does the gridview have any 'group by' functionality?

I need to display a table in the gridview, then allow for sorting on all the database table columns.

I also need to be able to 'group by' on some columns.

Any examples of this kind of functionality?

Comment: go with Telerik if you can afford it, it's well worth it in the long run

Comment: if your looking for free, theres a few decent examples on CodeProject, none that can shake a stick at Telerik though.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the built-in gridview doesn't have grouping. Third party controls like the [Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet/Grid/Examples/GroupBy/OutlookStyle/DefaultCS.aspx) have this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the GridViewHelper code here: http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm, I've used it and found it works a treat

Comment: Yeup - I was very surprised (and pleased!) when I found it!

Answer (score 0):

Sorting in gridview will result in, effectively, a grouping.  Say you have the data:

```
ID  Item
110 Pineapple
111 Orange
112 Apple
113 Pineapple
```

Sorting by the Item column would result in:

```
112 Apple
111 Orange
110 Pineapple
113 Pineapple
```

Are you looking for something else?